# create oracle PL/SQL Stored procedure that return information?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[model table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtT9T.png)

Hi,
This is a model of a table that I tried to create. I want to create a procedure that returns information about all the names in Sportif that practice a sport that we enter in a parameter

### For example if we are searching for who practices

NATATION
<== return
Mark,
Ben,
Jason;

---

I tried this but only select work if i put it in a procedure it have many error messages

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHER  (NOM_SPORT OUT VARCHAR2,NOM1 OUT VARCHAR2)
as
begin 
select NOM_SPORT, NOM1
from SPORT ,SPORTIF
where ID_SPORTIF =ID_SPORT
and NOM_SPORT ='Natation' 
end;
```

---

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  The Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/index.html) is always a good place to start .

Comment: Don't create tables in System schema.You need to add `IN` parameter instead of hard coding NOM_SPORT inside the procedure.

Comment: @Kumar i already have my tables(and they have information inside)  i just need to make a procedure that collect infromation from those two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of your parameters so they're not the same as columns in your tables, and use an `...INTO...` clause in your SELECT statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHER(pout_NOM_SPORT OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 pout_NOM1      OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT NOM_SPORT,
         NOM1
    INTO pout_NOM_SPORT,
         pout_NOM1
    FROM SPORT, 
         SPORTIF
    WHERE ID_SPORTIF = ID_SPORT AND
          NOM_SPORT ='Natation'
END CHER;
```

---

## EDIT

And now that we can see how you're calling your procedure, and the errors you're getting, we can see that the problem is that you're not passing any parameters to your procedure. You'll need to use something like:

```
DECLARE
  strNom_sport  VARCHAR2(100);
  strNom1       VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  CHER(strNom_sport, strNom1);
END;
```

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica You need to fix the procedure as the fetch returns more than one row